# Socket Error when uploading CarrierWave image after changing to chruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rvm, carrierwave, fog, chruby

My setup was working fine until I switched from RVM to CHRuby.

When I restarted the server and loaded the local page, I got a dialog box that looked like this.

https://superuser.com/questions/100013/why-does-the-mac-os-x-firewall-dialog-recurringly-pop-up-and-disappear-by-itself

I clicked 'Deny', but went back and enabled the firewall settings for ruby.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ExwV.jpg

I have checked my IAM security credentials and everything matches what is in the carrierwave initializer.

After some other testing I found that:

When I use other carrierwave uploaders within in the app, the images updates fine.  This leads me to believe my AWS security settings are fine.

A new photo saves just fine when excluding :image in params hash

```
@photo = Photo.new(photo_params.except("image"))
```

Could this be a datatabe issue within Postgres.  I just switched from SQlite to Postgres

My setup is

```
gem 'fog'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'carrierwave'
```

While trying to save a new record I now get the following error

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8522ms

Excon::Errors::SocketError - Bad address (Errno::EFAULT):
  excon (0.44.4) lib/excon/errors.rb:17:in `initialize'
  excon (0.44.4) lib/excon/connection.rb:175:in`rescue in request_call'
  excon (0.44.4) lib/excon/connection.rb:101:in `request_call'
  excon (0.44.4) lib/excon/middlewares/mock.rb:47:in`request_call'
  excon (0.44.4) lib/excon/middlewares/instrumentor.rb:22:in `request_call'
  excon (0.44.4) lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:15:in`request_call'
  excon (0.44.4) lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:15:in `request_call'
  excon (0.44.4) lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:15:in`request_call'
  excon (0.44.4) lib/excon/connection.rb:233:in `request'
  excon (0.44.4) lib/excon/middlewares/idempotent.rb:26:in`error_call'
  excon (0.44.4) lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:10:in `error_call'
  excon (0.44.4) lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:10:in`error_call'
  excon (0.44.4) lib/excon/connection.rb:256:in `rescue in request'
  excon (0.44.4) lib/excon/connection.rb:204:in`request'
  excon (0.44.4) lib/excon/middlewares/idempotent.rb:26:in `error_call'
  excon (0.44.4) lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:10:in`error_call'
  excon (0.44.4) lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:10:in `error_call'
  excon (0.44.4) lib/excon/connection.rb:256:in`rescue in request'
  excon (0.44.4) lib/excon/connection.rb:204:in `request'
  excon (0.44.4) lib/excon/middlewares/idempotent.rb:26:in`error_call'
  excon (0.44.4) lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:10:in `error_call'
  excon (0.44.4) lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:10:in`error_call'
  excon (0.44.4) lib/excon/connection.rb:256:in `rescue in request'
  excon (0.44.4) lib/excon/connection.rb:204:in`request'
  fog-core (1.29.0) lib/fog/core/connection.rb:81:in `request'
  fog-xml (0.1.1) lib/fog/xml/connection.rb:9:in`request'
  fog-aws (0.1.1) lib/fog/aws/storage.rb:587:in `_request'

and so on...

Comment: I think the original version, with `gem "fog"` should work. It may be that there is a configuration issue, rather than a broader gem issue, that is causing that Excon error. It looks likely to be an error in trying to connect to AWS, rather than something local.

Comment: I was getting the same kind of error whether i use fog or fog-aws.  It was working prior until we switched to postgres and changed to chruby

Comment: Yeah. To clarify, I think it might be an issue with the specifics of your carrierwave configuration, rather than the gems and whatnot around it. Not sure about that, but I would double check the settings you have there.

Answer (score 0):

During a new bundle install after updating the current version of ruby via chruby, openssl was change to 1.0.2 and that was causing all the problems.  Switching back to 1.0.1 solved the problem.

Others had the same issue.
https://github.com/excon/excon/issues/467

I had help from Jim at Codementor
https://www.codementor.io/thatrubylove